# Is it possible to revert a deleting status on a step function machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

My TI partner accidentally delete an step function machine and it stuck in deleting status because of the executions that are active, the question is if is it possible to revert the delete, maybe with aws customer support or any other way.

I tried re deploy cdk stack
edit from console

Comment: This is not possible. The only thing you can do is recreate it via CDK (assuming you have a CDK Script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to cancel a delete.

Luckily, it sounds like your State Machine definition is defined in CDK, which is good news. Once the executions finished and the State Machine deletes, you can redeploy it.

For the future, I would suggest using least-privileged console roles that don't allow resources to be deleted.